# HBql :: Any tips on how to limit query based on row ID?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop-plugins

Thanks for reading this one =)

I'm trying to figure out how to figure out how to limit query in HBql based on row ID. I've spent hours, looking up to see if there's any relevant article online.

So far, I haven't found any helpful document regarding this issue; HBql.com wasn't very helpful (maybe it's on there but I missed it).

I'd appreciate if you could give me any tips or documents that will help me with this issue.

-- FT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [WITH](http://hbql.com/statements/with-clause.html) clause. If you look down the page you can do "LIMIT limit_value".

Comment: P.S. Google is your friend, took me 2 minutes and I'd never heard of HBql before.

Comment: hmm... thank you for helping me; but I already stepped on that one. It wasn't particularly helpful.

Comment: Ah, well, I'm not really familiar with HBql. Have you tried Hive or Pig? I'm just starting to look into those, Hive can integrate to use HBase tables https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration